# PostgreSQL: Database structure for Chat Conversation

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am designing a Table for Chat Conversation. Instead of create 2 table: **Conversation and Message**. I just design 1 table: Conversation and use `JSONB` field for Message.

You guys check this photo:

[image]

Is this database structure solution good or bad? And if it's bad, is there other solutions for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to normalize your table structure.

The participants should go into separate table with columns `id_conversation` and `id_user`. It would be better for searching and updating than using a (json) array.

Same thing with `messages`. Why not storing them into a separate table with columns `id_conversation`, `timestamp`, `id_user`, `message_text`? It would be much better designed for searching and updating as well. And it makes your conversation table much smaller.

---

**Addionally**: What is that `participants` column for? If you have messages for each conversation you could easily ask the table for all users who committed a message to the conversation with something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user FROM messages WHERE id_conversation = 42
```

---

**Edit**:

On principle: 1M data sets are much but not a gigantic table. Postgres with a good table design should not have any problems with it. But I assume one conversation has much fewer messages so you can do a lot with filtering and indexing.

1.
I strongly recommend to think about some clever **indexes** for your tables which should make the searching really quick. Maybe an index over the message's timestamps could help and one over the conversion IDs:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_messages_timestamp
ON messages (timestamp);

CREATE INDEX idx_messages_conversations
ON messages (id_conversation);
```

If you want do fetch the newer messages it could be helpful to create the indexes with an `DESC` order (`... ON messages(... DESC)`)

2.
For really huge tables (I mean REALLY huge tables) it could be helpful to **partition** it. This splits your table internally on a certain criterion - maybe on timestamp (monthly or yearly for example). So if you mostly fetch some newer data the older ones will be archived in separate tables internally. So the query is only on the rows of the requested smaller table.

**But this is kind of advanced**: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Forget column `participants`. bro. If normalize your table structure (split into 2 tables: `Message` and `Conversation`), sure we need filter Message by conversation_id every Request if in `Pagination Process`. if there are too much rows in message Table, I think it's too slow!

Comment: Please provide your use cases and sample data in the question. When are you getting too much rows? What are you filtering.

Comment: Example if we have 1M row in Message table, we `SELECT 10 FROM messages WHERE id_conversation = 42` for every `Pagination Request`, It's slower than we `SELECT FROM conversation WHERE id = 42` and get `Message Column`

Comment: But what is in the message column? The whole conversation? What do you mean with `SELECT 10 ...`

Comment: Yes. Whole conversation messages in Message Column.

Comment: Hm, I cannot believe that it should be faster. Incl. the parsing of the json string etc. If your query of the messages is too slow you should think about indexes over timestamp and over conversation.

Comment: I understand what you said. Is that good if I use MongoDB to store message log instead?

Comment: I am not into MongoDB, so I cannot say if it would be a good idea. But I do not see why Postgres with a good table design (with indexes and maybe a partition of the the messages table or some clever materialization) shouldn't do this.

Comment: Added some more ideas for table design. But these are only ideas and depend hardly on your system. Some might work some not. Surely there are lot more.

Comment: @S-Man  I followed your way. but I have a question about id_conversation. How to get messages according to id_conversation. How to access id_conversation of chat room that we want.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you try to achieve. But why not `SELECT message_text FROM messages WHERE id_conversation = XYZ`